# how to exclude certain documents from Cloudant (or Mango) query?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-mango

I imported the IMDB movies-demo database to my CouchDB instance and am am learning about Mango by utilizing some Cloudant tutorials and references.

I wrote this query to identify documents wherein the actor's name is like "bruce".  Now I want to modify this to exclude certain documents from the result set.  For example Movie_name <> 'Monster'.

Is this possible and, if so, can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

```
{"selector":
  {"_id":
    {"$gt": null},
    "Person_name": {"$regex": "(?i)bruce"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `$ne` operator that can be used to match documents that are "not equal to" a given value.

```
{
  "selector":{
     "_id": {"$gt": null},
     "Person_name": {"$regex": "(?i)bruce"},
     "Movie_name": { "$ne": "Monster" }
  }
}
```

A word of caution: the use of `$regex` in a query is not a recipe for great performance because it inevitable forces CouchDB to do a manual scan of all the documents in the database, rather than taking advantage of a pre-built index. Similarly, the `$ne` operator has similar performance characteristics.

The recommended practice with a Cloudant database (a hosted CouchDB service) is to create a [type=text](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/cloudant_query.html#creating-an-index) index on the fields you are querying. This index will allow you to use the `$text` operator in your queries in place of your regular expression, which should be much more efficient.